# I hope it's not an old question as I'm brand new here

Tags: boot, usb

I'm an expeienced Ubuntuist but I've hit an istallation snag. I've just acquired a Framework laptop. It powers on but there's no OS of any description on it. I've downloaded U22.04 to a 2 TB USB drive but, when I boot the laptop, the BIOS sees nothing at all and just tells me I need to install a boot drive. I have no other computer available to me, just this Android tablet with limited storage space. Is it an issue of my USB device not being bootable? If I had a Windows or Linux box, I'd know how to proceed but, without that, I'm totally lost. How do I make a USB image visible to the BIOS?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Based on your description, it is not sufficient to download the Ubuntu 22.04 ISO into a 2TB USB. You have to use a special process to "burn" the ISO into the USB drive. To do this you will need another computer. This will delete **everything** you have in your 2TB USB drive. A 2TB USB is simply overkill for this purpose.

Comment: How did you download the 22.04 installation ISO file?

Comment: warning: the 2TB USB drive is *almost certainly* a scam USB with actually only about 32GB of storage. That means anything you put on it can potentially just get lost/disappear. See https://datarecovery.com/2022/03/the-2tb-flash-drive-scam-why-high-capacity-flash-drives-are-fakes/ and *please, please* test the drive before you put anything important on it!

Answer (score 1):

### Boot Ubuntu on Windows UEFI computer without USB or DVD

There are a number of ways to make a bootable drive without need for a USB.

- Use Windows Disk Management to create 4GB FAT32 partition on the Target disk.
- Copy/Paste contents of ISO file to the new partition. I use 7Zip or P7Zip
- Reboot pressing F2, F9, F10, F12, etc and select UEFI Ubuntu to boot.
- Install Ubuntu to a 25+GB partition on the target using the "Something else" install option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you flashed the ubuntu image to the drive to make it a bootable drive or have you just copied the file across?
You need to use a tool like Etcher to write your Ubuntu image to the drive to ensure that the BIOS can see it and boot from it.

There's a good guide here that you can follow: https://itsfoss.com/intsall-ubuntu-on-usb/

Comment: Yes, as I said up top, this is exactly the trouble. If I had another computer, I  would know exactly what to do. I've iinstalled various distros at least 20 times over the years, always from a bootable medium. What I'm trying to do, now, however, is to install without another computer to make the bootable medium. My question, essentially, is whether this  is possible and how one might do it?